# In VBA, Not able to null the string value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In Excel,

```
AN201   BOS 306=1234    035=Yes 102=Yes 100=70  097=Yes Sometext shouldcome after a longspace thankyou
AN201   BOS 306=1235    035=No  102=No  100=71  097=No  This is second scenario thankyou
```

[in Excel, requirement is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T53B9.jpg)

And the OUTPUT should be in NOTEPAD,

```
AN201@#BOS@#3061234@#035Yes@#102Yes@#10070@#097Yes@#Sometext    shouldcome after a longspace      thankyou
AN201@#BOS@#3061234@#035Yes@#102Yes@#10070@#097Yes@#This is second scenario 
     thankyou
```

And the script which I tried is,

```
Sub Characterpostion()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim str As String
Dim cellvalue As String

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
FilePath = FreeFile
CellData = ""
Open "C:\Users\Antony\Music\Excel Macros\Text2.txt" For Output As #2 

For i = 1 To LastRow
For j = 1 To LastCol


Select Case j
Case 1
n = 5 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
Case 2
n = 3 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
Case 3
n = 8 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
Case 4
n = 7 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
Case 5
n = 7 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
Case 6
n = 6 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
Case 7
n = 7 - Len(Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value))
End Select

CellData = CellData & Space(n) & Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) & "@#"

If CellData Like "*=*" Then
Dim WrdArray() As String
WrdArray() = Split(CellData, "=")
str = WrdArray(0) + WrdArray(1)
Print #2 , str
Else
End If
Next j
Print #2 , CellData
CellData = ""
Next i
Close #2 
End Sub
```

But CellData stores all the case at a time... I am not able to null the CellData to restore the new value.

Appreciate your immediate response!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try a join on a 1-D array and replace.

```
with ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        str = join(application.transpose(application.transpose(.Cells(i, "A").resize(1, LastCol).Value)), "@#")
        str = replace(str, "=", vbnullstring)

        Print #2 , str
    Next i
end with
```

The `Space(n)` you originally used concerns me. This is typically used for fixed width text files.

Comment: Excellent..It works fine...But header is also displaying

Comment: Your sample data had no header but maybe `For i = 2 To LastRow` will resolve the issue.

Comment: yeah thats my bad..anyway everything works fine...appreciating your immediate help